# How do I make boostrap work for my react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have this code. The code was generated with create-react-app and build upon. I am totally new to react and have no idea why my react-bootstrap is not registering. Any help would be appreciated. I made the repo public so feel free to pull it and please anyone more clever then I am, if you can please provide answer why the bootstrap is not registering.

Thank you very much !

Link to repo - https://github.com/ghost0124/CthulhuMythosWeb

Answer (score 0):

You have to link bootstrap styling to your react styling.

- Paste this `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in your index.css or App.css file
- Add style link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />` to index.html file in public folder